# Insert number 0, all other numbers counting 1 up

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql-issue with my column `position`. If i insert some new stuff on my website, my table looks like this:

[image]

The column `position` indicates the actual position of the divs. If I drag n drop the divs, it looks like this:

[image]

So the div with the title entry3 is on the first line, the div with the title entry2 is on the second line and the div with the title entry1 is on the last line.

If I add a element now, it should get the position 0, the element with position 0 should get position 1, the element with position 1 should get position 2 and so on... I don't know if this is possible with a pure sql-query. I am grateful for every response.
Misch

Comment: Post table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the number with 1 with the following statement:

```
UPDATE Posts SET position = position + 1;
```

Then simply add the new row.

I don't know if its the best to do it in pure sql it recommends on your software.

Comment: Perfect, simple like that :) thank you very much. Misch